# Changing a link's href attribute based on it's text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have seen similar threads and have tried the syntax's in their solutions, but nothing is working.

I want to change the href attribute of all links of a certain type a page, based on the text of the link. Here is what I have now:

```
$('.class li a').attr('href', '#' + $(this).text());
```

`$(this).text()` doesn't seem to be returning anything. It has been awhile since I've worked with jQuery so I am confused by this problem. I have also tried `.val()` and `.html()`.

Comment: Unless you're clicking the link, $(this).text() doesn't apply because it refers to nothing. You'll need to use each().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, `$(this)` is not referencing the current `a` tag.

You can try this:

```
$('.class li a').each(function(){ 
       $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it has been awhile. Will accept when I can (10 minutes).

Comment: Atleast use `$.each()`: it's several times faster as a loop: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/7

Answer (score 1):

The `this` reference `$('.class li a').attr('href', '#' + $(this).text());` is not the link tag.. jQuery offers 2nd arg to also be a function inside which `this` will be referring to the link tag.. So something like below should do the trick.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WVmYB/2/)

Try,

```
$('.class li a').attr('href', function () { 
    return '#' + $(this).text()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class li a").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).text()); 
});
```